# Rails Development with MySQL:Inserting data into tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, irb

I downloaded a rails project.
Bundled it.
Run migrations.

Now the tables are empty. Which is the best way to fill it. irb or migrations itself. ?

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

Comment: What do you mean by "the tables are empty"? do you mean you want to add columns to the tables or simply you want to seed data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use seeds.rb to fill the tables.

Create /db/seeds.rb

```
5.times do |i|
  Model.create(name: "xxx")
end
```

And run rake db:seed.

```
rake db:seed
```

Look "Migrations and Seed Data" in rails guide.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a seeds feature to populate the db with initial data, check out this guide, paragraph 8

[Active Record Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those is best way to do.You should be doing **`CRUD`** operations in order to keep your Rails project up and running.

By doing so,you should be able to **create**,**edit**,**update** and **destroy** the Records.

You have to read these [**Guides**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).You need it.